# Rails best practice for creating a model during the creation of a separate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

So, I've got two models: `User` and `Group`.

`User belongs_to :group`

and

`Group has_many :users`.

When creating a new `User`, I want to check for an already created `Group` and assign them, or create a new `Group` based on user-supplied information. `Group.find_or_create_by_name("Name")` seems like a great way to do this, but my question is where should this be located? I'm guessing that following "Fat Models, skinny Controllers" it should be in `user.rb`. If it's in the model, what is the best way to pass in user-supplied strings on user creation? Should I set up a method in `user.rb` and then call that method in `users_controller.rb`?

And I guess a related question: I know that my schema should reflect

```
create_table "users" do |t|
  t.integer "group_id"
```

for the purpose of querying. How exactly does Rails "automagically" link these? When creating my `Group` model, I'm guessing it needs to have a `string:id` column, and Rails just links the two?

Sorry for my obvious lack of understanding on associations, but I'm trying not to just hack something together that works awkwardly, and want to make sure I understand the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, according to what you wrote, a group can have multiple users in it, but a user can only be part of a single group.

Usually, a group can have multiple members and a user can be member of multiple groups. To achieve that, you create an association model, called `membership`.

So, your user model have :

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :groups, :through => :memberships
```

And your group model have :

```
has_many :memberships
has_many :members, :through => memberships
```

The association will have a table on it's own that will be something like :

```
create_table "memberships" do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.timestamps
end

add_index :memberships, :group_id
add_index :memberships, :user_id
```

To answer your original question, if you have to create a group when a user is created regardless of the way he is created, I would create an Active Record Callback in the user model :

```
after_create :create_group

def create_group
   # whatever logic and create group
end
```

For more information about Active Record Callbacks, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

If the group you are creating is related to the information entered in a form (view) and is not directly related to the user, then you would have to do the creation of the group in the controller.  Something like :

```
def create
   @group = Group.build(params[:group])
   @group.save!
   @user = User.build(params[:user])
   @user.group_id = @group.id
   @user.save!
end
```

Or, cleaner way :

```
def create
   @group = Group.build(params[:group])
   @group.save!
   @user = @group.users.build(params[:user])
   @user.save!
end
```

Comment: Yes, a `User` can only belong to a single `Group`, so the extra abstraction of a `Membership` association model would be unnecessary (although I had not even considered that, thanks).

Comment: Also, just to make sure I understand correctly: In your example of creating a `Group` in `User#create`, there is no requirement for assignment? Ie, I don't need to do something like `@user.group_id = @group.id`?

Comment: @oflannabhra Yes, you would have to. Unless you do something like `@group.users.build(params[:user])`. I updated my answer with both scenario.